# Drupal 7: CKEditor disappears after saving content

Tags: drupal-7, ckeditor

I recently updated Drupal to 7.39 and CKEditor to 7.x-1.16 and I am now experiencing some bizarre behavior from the editor.

If I create new content, I have the editor in place. Once I save the content and come back, the editor is gone and is replaced by rendered HTML code. I am also seeing this when going in to edit *some* existing content. All content tested are the exact same content type.

This behavior occurs both in the body and the summary.

I have opened the page while running the JS console and I am seeing the following error:

**/ckeditor/xss

500 (Internal Server Error)**

I do not see this error on the content where the editor is appearing.

Any assistance on this is greatly appreciated! Let me know if I can provide any additional details to help troubleshoot.

Thanks!